# ContentProvider or Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

I am writing an application that shows "Japanese Traditional Time" (JTT for short). There are several components (notification, widgets, application itself, alarms) which all use the same data - current JTT.

My current version uses a single service that does all the calculation and uses a Handler to notify everyone about "ticking", mimicking `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

However with alarms I need to also have a way to translate "usual time" to JTT and vice versa. The calculations are quite CPU-heavy (it's all based on sunrises and sunsets) and thus I prefer having it all done in a single place and then cached (calculating stuff knowing sunrise and sunset times is not as heavy).

So I have several ways to do that now:

- Keep it all in Service

  - And use binding to request the data I need. It's actually already done in one case and seems a bit cumbersome since I have to handle asynchronous responses
- Move to content provider

  - And use content observers instead of broadcasting
  - Or send broadcasts from provider
- Combine both ways

  - Use content provider to calculate the data for service which in turn will broadcast it when needed

Which would be better? Maybe something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sticking with "just service" - I have discovered Sticky Broadcasts which actually cover the problem I had with common Broadcasts (having to request latest data from service after registering but before getting the first "tick") and that leaves me with much less cases where I need actual service connection.

Answer (score 0):

Content providers are for structured data, so it doesn't really fit your use case. Not sure what you mean by 'asynchronous responses'? Calling a remote service is usually just like a local function call, it will block and return a value when done. If you have to notify multiple components a broadcast is the way to go. Explore using a LocalBroadcast if all components are in the same process (check Android support library source), or set a permission on it to make sure other apps cannot get it if you need to send a system-wide (regular) one.

Comment: Right now I'm using `Messenger` to communicate with service, so to request data from bound service I create a message and send it, then get response in my own `Handler`.

Comment: But I will look into synchronous communication, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking about an AIDL-based service where you simply call methods on the local stub and thus get synchronous invocations.