# Custom adapter using bound service - when to unbind?

Tags: android, android-adapter, aidl

The setup: custom adapter that feeds data into `ListView`. Data is based on some numbers calculated by external service. I am using AIDL to bind the service and get the data I need.

Problem: How do I know when to unbind the service? Connection is private to adapter itself and the only way to detect that whole application is shutting down is overriding `unregisterDataSetObserver`. Or at least I didn't find another way and this one worked well with same adapter using content provider+content observer. Does not work with AIDL though - I'm getting the `ServiceConnectionLeaked` error.

I know I can add a "unbindFromService" method to my adapter and call it from onDestroy() of my activity but that isn't elegant enough for me. I'd prefer some "honest" trigger if possible.

Comment: Why the service connection is private and used in the adapter? Can you handle it on the activity level and pass only the data to the adapter? Then you can use bind/unbind on the activity's onCreate/onDestroy.

Comment: The data isn't just coming from service, it has to be requested. Adapter knows which data it needs, no one else does.

Comment: This means your adapter should ask for the data from some other component (e.g., Activity), which should fetch the data then. Just some refactoring and using of [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The adapter is usually only responsible for rendering data and some event handling, like onItemClick and so on. You can handle the connection on the adapter level (like you've described), but it will not be elegant. Hope it will help.

Comment: Adapter is the only component that needs that data and it is the only component that knows how to handle it. Earlier versions of my application used "centralized" service access through activity, but now only adapter is working with service. I don't like the idea of adding another layer of indirection by moving the connection object to activity.

Comment: Then I have nothing to add. The last thing I've found in [Bound services doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), see Additional notes section: `You should usually pair the binding and unbinding during matching bring-up and tear-down moments of the client's lifecycle`

Comment: I do binding in `registerDataSetObserver` but unbinding in `unregisterDataSetObserver` is too late. That's why the question.

Comment: I would go for Vadim's first comment, bind/unbind in Activity's onCreate()/onDestroy(). If you really want all the other calls (that generate data) to be performed by the adapter, you could hand the adapter a handle to the service using something like setService(aService) method on your custom adapter. When your activity is destroyed, first unset the service handle in the adapter (setService(null)) and then unbind. This seems to be quite analogous to the swapCursor(aCursor) method in CursorAdapter (although you still leave data retrieval to the adapter, but that is what you wanted).

Comment: I'm a little bit curious about "call it from onDestroy() of my activity but that isn't elegant enough for me". Why? Is it because you want to make the service irrelevant with activity but only with the adapter? But the default service lifecycle is related to the activity. The activity has been stopped and thus the system thinks the service is no longer required and probably stops the service, which causes your problem.

Comment: No, the service is exported and is used in different other processes too - including widgets. Basically there are multiple independent clients and adapter is one of those.

Answer (score 4):

Implement `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in your CustomAdapter and then from your activity call

```
mAdapter.setActivity(this);
```

Adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

    Activity mActivity;

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
           /* or you could remove setactivity and do below operation in Constructor */
        mActivity = activity;
        mActivity.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        /*unregister so that you do not get callbacks after activity is destroyed*/
        if(activity instanceof MainActivity)   
              mActivity.getApplication().unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

            /*unregister your activity or in any other callbacks*/
    }

    /* skipped other dummy functions*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Connection is private to adapter` is wrong. ***Adapter is Context-less and so a service should not be private to the adapter***.

Your adapter will never be able to bind to the service without a Context. Inherently, you have a function that provides a Context for your adapter to bind to the service. Therefore, the bound connection is not private to your Adapter: It is the Context passed that allowed its creation.

The real problem is that AFAIK there is no way to listen to the context. Meaning, say that you held the context instance inside your adapter: There is no way to allow the adapter to listen to this context and somehow know that the Activity is done. This leads you to accept the not-elegant-enough-for-you solution: Your activity should notify the adapter which is using its context! Otherwise, you will end up with a more hacked-up solution.

---

Please notice that the whole debate in the comments deals with your "service is private to the adapter" thingy. In reality, the elegant way to do this would be to have a ServiceProvider interface that provides the connection and this would be implemented by your activity. You adapter should be initialized with a ServiceProvider passed. Some functions would be `getConnection` and `isRunning`. In this way, your Activity will take care of the connection while the Adapter uses it. (***Synchronization***)

Comment: Adapter is not context-less actually: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getContext()

Comment: ServiceProvider interface is "yet another layer of indirection" which I tend to see as an unneeded clutter.

Comment: @aragaer ArrayAdapter is an implementation. Passing the Context in the constructor is merely a choice. It is used to inflate/create views.

Comment: LikeWise, you probably chose to use a context in the constructor to initialize the service connection.

Comment: Well, my custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter. And I do inflate/create views based on data received from service.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Service to insert fresh data into a SQLite table or to refresh a ContentProvider, then use a SimpleCursorAdapter (android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter which is backward compatible) and the LoaderManager, SQLiteCursorLoader/CursorLoader, Loader pattern to show the data on a List or ListFragment.

The SQLiteCursorLoader is not given by the Android SDK, but Mark Murphy have one on in GitHub, so you could take a look at it if you want to persist the fresh data in a local SQLite DB.

Since the Service can be independent from the underlying data in SQLite and the Adapter for the list you can unbind it when is finished inserting new data or refreshing the provider so you can procede with the recommended patterns to unbind Services (See this question: [Android: How to safely unbind a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614335/android-how-to-safely-unbind-a-service)) and take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle.

I really hope this gives you a hint. Good luck!

Comment: It's not that much data actually and as I mentioned before, I did try using `ContentProvider` with `MatrixCursor` which worked well enough, but [I have been told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843105/contentprovider-or-service) that it is not what I should use here.