# How to unbind a service in Adapter instead of Fragment or Activity

Tags: android

How to unbind a service when the service is bind in the adapter not in fragment or Activity? (Because `onDestroy()` is not available in Adapter)

Comment: [Try to check inside this link hope that will work for u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886899/custom-adapter-using-bound-service-when-to-unbind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public method `unbind` in Adapter and call it in `Activity` in `onDestroy()`?